# Error on mysqli select

Tags: mysqli

I have this select:

```
<?php
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `country`, COUNT(`country`) AS `numar` FROM logs GROUP BY country where username = '$username'");
$stmt2->execute();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $country, $numar);
$stmt2->store_result();
if($stmt2->num_rows > 0)  //To check if the row exists
  {
      while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2))
{
  echo "<tr>                

                    <tr>
                    <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$country</td>
                    <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$numar</td>

                    </tr>
                    ";

        }           

} else {
echo"<tr>
<td colspan=\"5\" class=nn><div style=\"text-align:center;\">Not have websites in your account! Click <a href=\"addwebsite\">here</a> to add a website!</div></td>
</tr>";
}   
?>
```

when run this select, return this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /nginx/html/site/reports.php on line 115  and line 115 is line with select! I tryed with `and` on select but same error! Where is problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the sql as mentioned below

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `country`, COUNT(`country`) AS `numar` FROM logs where username = '$username' GROUP BY country ");
```